# syntax error, unexpected T_STRING PHPMAILER line 22

Tags: syntax-error, phpmailer

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home1/mast1456/public_html/src/PHPMailer.php on line 22
>
> line 22 namespace PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

Answer (score -1):

This means you're running a *very* old version of PHP that doesn't understand namespaces, which were introduced in PHP 5.3. You need to run at least PHP 5.5 for PHPMailer anyway, but I would recommend you use PHP 7.4 for anything you're developing now.